# Functional equation related to the supercritical Galton-Watson process

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Consider the Galton-Watson process $(Z_n)_n$ and the martingale $M_n = \mu^{-n}Z_n$. We assume that $\mu > 1$, i.e. our Galton-Watson process is supercritical and $\mathbb{E}(M_\infty) < \infty$. Prove that the Laplace transformation $\varphi(t) := \mathbb{E}(e^{-tM_\infty})$ of the limit random RV $M_\infty$ and the probability generating function $\psi$ of the offspring distribution, i.e. $\psi(s) = \mathbb{E}(s^X) = \sum_{k \ge 0} p_ks^k$ for $\lvert s \rvert \le 1$, satisfy the functional equation
>
> $$\varphi(t) = \psi(\varphi(t/\mu)), \qquad  \varphi(0) = 1, \qquad \partial^+ \varphi(0) = -\mathbb{E}(M_\infty)$$

The second and third points are clear to me, but I do not understand how to prove the first one. I tried to just plug in the Laplacian in $\psi$, but the resulting term is just messy.

Comment: Is the answer I wrote below clear?

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot to accept. I am sorry. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_{n-1,j}$ denote the number of descendants in generation $n$ of the $j$'th member of the first generation. Then $$Z_n=\sum_{j=1}^{Z_1} Z_{n-1,j} \,,$$ where the summands are i.i.d. (with the law of $Z_{n-1}$) and independent of $Z_1$. Thus $M_{n-1,j}:=Z_{n-1,j}/\mu^{n-1}$ satisfy
$$M_n=\frac1{\mu}\sum_{j=1}^{Z_1}M_{n-1,j} \,.$$
Let $\varphi_n(t):=E(e^{-tM_n})$. Then
$$E(e^{-tM_n} | Z_1)= \varphi_{n-1}(t/\mu)^{Z_1} \tag{*}\,,$$
so    taking expectation of both sides (thinking of the RHS of $(*)$  as $s^{Z_1}$), gives
$$\varphi_n(t)=E(e^{-tM_n})= E\Bigl(\varphi_{n-1}(t/\mu)^{Z_1}\Bigr)=
\psi \bigl(\varphi_{n-1}(t/\mu)\bigr)  \tag{**}\,.$$
Since $\varphi_n(t) \to \varphi(t)$ by bounded convergence and $\psi$ is continuous, we infer from $(**)$ that
$$\varphi(t)= 
\psi \bigl(\varphi(t/\mu)\bigr)   \,.$$